# Override mime type with VS Web Dev Server

Tags: visual-studio, xbap, cassini, mime-types

I would like to serve xbaps from the VS web dev server (cassini) to Firefox, but when served from the dev server, Firefox offers to download this file. As far as I can tell, this is because the dev server is serving the xbap file with a mime type of "application/octet-stream" instead of "application/x-ms-xbap", which works when served from IIS.

Does anyone know how to change the mime type which the dev server uses for *.xbap files?

Comment: see update re xbap in ff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't. WevDev.WebHost is fairly clumsy when issuing content-types and has a very limited range of specific content-types.

You can use [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com).  The latest release provides extended content-type support, including .xbap.

see http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/49870#894160 for a complete list of supported types.

**Update**: your problem may be that you installed FF after 3.5sp1 and do not have the `NPWPF.dll` in your FF plugins directory. Do you have this file?

**Update 2**
I have just released a version of CassiniDev that is a great drop in replacement for Visual Studio's Development server. It's enhancements include improved content-type support and integrated traffic logging/viewing.

http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/05/22/release-cassinidev-for-visual-studio-2008-a-drop-in.aspx

Comment: Hi, will try out CassiniDev - I didn't see any obvious links on whether I could use it as a drop in replacement - will have to google some more. WRT your problem, I've found that just copying in NPWPF.dll, either into the FF plugins directory or "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Windows Presentation Foundation" gets it going again. We had this problem when upgrading to Windows 7 machines.

Comment: @douglas - i just released the visual studio replacement - http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/05/22/release-cassinidev-for-visual-studio-2008-a-drop-in.aspx - give it a shot and leave a review/feed back on the codeplex site.

Comment: I'm now using CassiniDev for this, and it's working perfectly.

Comment: @douglas- glad to hear that it is working well for you. I like it too.;-)

Comment: Does CassiniDev support the `<staticContent>` settings in the `<system.webServer>` section in the web.config?

Comment: @travis - i really can't say without writing some tests. perhaps this is something you can verify.

Answer (score 1):

It probably too late now, but for others who get that problem here is how to solve it:

I solved it for mp4 videos but it is the same principal for any mime,
just revise to your needs.

I assume you use vs2012, create IHttpHandler and copy this code into it:

```
public class Mp4Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(context.request.PhysicalPath));
        context.Response.End();
    }

public bool IsReusable{ get{ return false;}}
}
```

And remember to add to your web.config file under system.web:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.mp4" type="[your-namespace].Mp4Handler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

By doing so you will not need CassiniDev to serve mp4 correctly anymore, however,
CassiniDev is not evil and worth keeping - without it I wouldn't be able to verify what the problem was in the 1st place.

Comment: will this work with VS2010 also before I try to implement this?

Comment: I didn't test it in vs2010 but it should work there too, there is no reason to believe otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with VS 2010 SP1, you can now use IIS Express instead of Cassini for your web projects, which gives you full control of your MIME types.

More information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/03/14/enabling-iis-express-support-in-vs-2010-sp1.aspx

Comment: Does IIS Express support the `<staticContent>` settings in the `<system.webServer>` section in the web.config?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021946/add-mime-mapping-in-web-config-for-iis-express