# Fontello doesn't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, production, fontello

Hi everyone at this time I'm installing a production server under linux with apache + passenger + rvm + rails 4, almost everithing is working ok except the fontello's icons

the directory of the principal fontello folder is in here:

```
/project/app/assets/stylesheets/fontello/
```

In development the app looks like this

[image: development]

In production looks like this

[image: production]

so as you can see doesn't find the icons
Can somebody tell me please how can I fix it

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you fixed it? If so, how?

Comment: Doesn't seems like the correct way to do it to me, but I'm glad it's working for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd need to view source on production to truly help here - but assuming you have your relative and absolute path stuff sorted out/setup right a few different things could be happening here.

- Most common thing is that your production web server may not yet be setup with right mime types for font files. often ttf or woff have to be setup manually on different web servers (Reference: [Add MIME mapping in web.config for IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021946/add-mime-mapping-in-web-config-for-iis-express))
- Otherwise possibly SSL vs non-SSL crankiness w/the font file links?

Let us know if you get it fixed and how!