# Adding mapping to web.config slows down website

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, web-config, mime-types

I'm using VS2013 Express for Web + .NET 4.5 + IIS Express 8.

I followed the instructions from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021946/add-mime-mapping-in-web-config-for-iis-express?rq=1) and added the MIME mapping to my web.config, but this has slowwwwed down my website to a crawl. Both debug and published versions are slow. Removing the mapping brings in back to normal. Does someone know what may have been causing this, or at least a method to dig it out?

My mapping is the same as given in the post I mentioned:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Instead of adding mime type in web.config. Try adding it on IIS level-http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx and then see whether its improves performance or not

Answer (score 0):

The mime type for *.woff is officially **application/font-woff**.
Try to replace the *x-font-woff* with *font-woff*.

Example:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```