# CSS @font-face doesnt work

Tags: css

I've been looking everywhere but I still couldn't find an answer.
Google Chrome does not recognize the font.
Here is part of my code, hope it will help you tell me where I'm wrong.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'N';
src: url('../fontawesome-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('../fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
   url('../f.woff') format('woff'), 
   url('../fontawesome-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
   url('../fontawesome-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
   }

.btn {
  font-family: 'N';
 display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
 etc....
```

The files are in the right folder.

Comment: Check your web inspector console for errors. What does it say?

Comment: upload your site on web server then check it out. If still not working then give online link with `HTTP`.

Comment: The woff format which Google Chrome uses has different file name f.woff, are you sure this is the file name?

Answer (score 0):

put the font files side of your pages in same level for check mapping and be sure the path is correct.

if you are using  a web server (IIS etc..) you may need add the MIME type in your config file: [Add MIME mapping in web.config for IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021946/add-mime-mapping-in-web-config-for-iis-express)