# Resource in Content folder not found using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to load a `trackCues.vtt` file that is stored in my solution and I am trying to load this resource in my view in the following manner:

```
<video style="margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:30px" width="800" height="600" controls>
    <source src='@Url.Content("~/Content/AudioAssets/speechSample.mp4")' type="video/mp4">
    <track src='@Url.Content("~/Content/AudioAssets/trackCues.vtt")' kind="metadata" default>
</video>
```

however when the page loads I receive the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost:33862/Content/AudioAssets\trackCues.vtt

I'm not sure why this is failing as the path look correct (I must be wrong about that though)

Note: I load my video out of the same directory and using the same syntax so I'm not sure why the `.vtt` file won't load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Specify Mime-Type in ApplicationHost.config**

Add the following configuration to the `staticContent` section of `ApplicationHost.config`

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".vtt" mimeType="text/vtt" />
```

The configuration file be found at:

```
%HOMEPATH%\Documents\IISExpress\config\ApplicationHost.config
```

---

**Specify Mime-Type in Web.config** (worked for OP)

This configuration allows the the project to be deployed without having to change any server settings.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".vtt" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".vtt" mimeType="text/vtt" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Replace the `<user>` placeholder with the username that you used to login with.  A shortcut is to look here `%HOMEPATH%\Documents\IISExpress\config`

Comment: I found it- had my documents folder stored on a different machine on the network. Still not working after adding the mimeMap though. same error

Comment: Maybe try restarting IIS Express?

Comment: based on your answer, I found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021946/add-mime-mapping-in-web-config-for-iis-express   you put me on the right track so I'd love to accept your answer- just please update to also include this method (which I believe to be better anyway since it is portable between machines)

Comment: Done :)  I agree that specifying this in `Web.config` might save some headache down the line.  One of the benefits of specifying these things on a server-wide configuration though is that all sites will be updated.  In any case, glad this worked for you.

Comment: good point. didnt think of the advantage of specifying through the server