# Google fonts that I loaded using https serves as https but blocked as non-https, please someone check my code

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, fonts

We have a website which was running on `http://` earlier. We moved the whole site to `https://`. To prevent man in the middle attack we make everything https so chrome will not show "load unsafe script" in the right. I changed all my http link to https. I was using this code to load my google fonts

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' />
```

This code look fine to me and I click on the stylesheet and it's show me font files loaded through https. Now I seen in firefox dev tool

```
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSugdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2”
[Learn More]
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2”
[Learn More]
```

The learn more link goes to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

The problem is I still get mixed content error when I have a https link on my website. Same way I am loading stylesheet using `/abc.css` Since the site running under https the link will be fetch as https. Now when I import a font in
the css file like

```
@font-face{font-family:test;src:url(../fonts/test.eot?v=4.4.0)
```

The firefox show me warning that the font is loaded with http even it's https. the relative path of fonts come with error that it's mixed with unsecure content.

I check on chrome and there is no such error. It's only happen in Firefox. How I can sort out this error in firefox. The same fonts giving me exception in Edge that " HTTPS security is compromised by data:/font".

Did anyone have sort out this kind of error. Thanks

Comment: cache issue? really, there's nothing you've posted that would account for such odd behaviour

Comment: Possible dupicate question, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021946/add-mime-mapping-in-web-config-for-iis-express)

Comment: @JaromandaX I check with ctrl + u it's https, I tried with incognito window, same issue is showing.

Comment: but in the browser network console it's http?

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly

Comment: well, that's not right, I've never had an issue with google fonts in firefox

Comment: @ManushankaSenanayake same happen with google fonts, so I don't think that can cause issues.

Comment: Replace `https://yourlink` with `//yourlink`. Let the browser handle `http[s]`

Comment: @input I will try it today and let you know about it.