# Static Content error debbug in localhost with VisualStudio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, mime-types, static-content

I have added some mime that I needed for my project in MVC5 because in production it did not work.

```
<system.webServer>
 <staticContent>      
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" /> 
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" /> 
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".js.min" mimeType="text/javascript" /> 
 </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Once added I have published and the app works correctly.

When trying to debug the app in local with VisualStudio, it doesn't find any mime.
[image]

If I comment the code of the Web.config it works correctly in local but not in production.

How can I not be commenting and uncommenting this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the following implementation and I have managed to make everything work correctly both in the production version and in the local version

```
<system.webServer>
 <staticContent>    
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />  
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" /> 
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" /> 
    <remove fileExtension=".js.min" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".js.min" mimeType="text/javascript" /> 
 </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

I could find the solution here [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021946/add-mime-mapping-in-web-config-for-iis-express)